# select table using complicated query

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I have 2 tables with above fields.

I have created below query

```
  SELECT DISTINCT H.HolidayId,H.HolidayDate,H.Description,CH.ClientId,
        case when CH.HolidayId is not null then 1 else 0 end as  IsHoliday
        FROM Holiday H LEFT JOIN ClientHolidays CH ON h.HolidayId = CH.HolidayId
```

[image]

But I need to list all holidays with IsHoliday field if client has added as holiday then   IsHoliday field should come as 1 else 0

And when querying with ClientId. It should list all holidays depend upon clientId

I need result as below

[image]

While passing client id i need to get all holidays with IsHoliday field should come as 0 or 1

Comment: That is what you are doing in the above query ri8?

Comment: I Need the list based on client id

Comment: What is your clear Expected result?

Comment: I need to result all holidays with IsHoliday field 1 or 0 depend upon client id

Comment: where is the "complicated" query?  I came to look for it but it doesn't appear to be there...

Comment: Richard Please give me result. I need to complete it today

Comment: Update your question with Expected result... I think you need `IsHoliday value 1 for 10042 to 10049..` Right?

Comment: Hi Jesuraja i have updated . Please provide me answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used your queries after 2 days only i found bug in that. then i found a solution for that.

Below is the solution:

```
  SELECT h.HolidayId, HolidayDate,Description,CASE WHEN ClientID IS NULL THEN 0 WHEN ClientID != @ClientId THEN 0   ELSE 1 END AS IsHoliday
                        FROM HOLIDAY h LEFT OUTER JOIN CLIENTHOLIDAYS ch ON ch.HolidayId = h.HolidayId
                        WHERE ClientId = @ClientId OR ClientID is null or ClientID is not null
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try below query, it will work as per the requirement :)

```
SELECT h.HolidayId, HolidayDate,
CASE WHEN ClientID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsHoliday
FROM HOLIDAY h
LEFT OUTER JOIN CLIENTHOLIDAYS ch ON ch.HolidayId = h.HolidayId
WHERE ClientId = 1 OR ClientID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT DISTINCT H.HolidayId
    ,H.HolidayDate
    ,H.Description
    ,CH.ClientId
    ,CASE 
        WHEN CH.clientid IS NOT NULL
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS IsHoliday
FROM Holiday H
LEFT JOIN ClientHolidays CH 
    ON h.HolidayId = CH.HolidayId
```

Comment: It is listing all holidays

Comment: That is what you want ri8 , you want list all holidays but 1 if it is in client else 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT H.HolidayId,H.HolidayDate,H.Description,
        CASE WHEN CH.HolidayId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsHoliday
FROM    Holiday H LEFT JOIN 
        ClientHolidays CH ON h.HolidayId = CH.HolidayId
WHERE   CH.ClientId = 8 OR CH.ClientId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comments I get the sense you don't want all holidays. You just want the holidays for each client. If that is the case you should use an `inner join` . Also in this scenario the isHoliday field is moot because you only get the results for holidays that clients actually take so is holiday will always be 1.

```
SELECT H.HolidayId,H.HolidayDate,H.Description,CH.ClientId,
       case when CH.HolidayId is not null then 1 else 0 end as  IsHoliday
FROM Holiday H inner JOIN 
ClientHolidays CH 
ON h.HolidayId = CH.HolidayId
```